# Stationary test error in Time Series using R

Tags: r, time-series

I have half hourly data for 5 years measuring the electricity load.
I checked for stationary with `acf`, which shows it is non stationary. But when I used `adf.test` to check stationary, it showed opposite result:

```
adf.test(tsr1$LOAD.MW.,alternative="stationary")

# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

# data:  tsr1$LOAD.MW.
# Dickey-Fuller = -9.7371, Lag order = 11, p-value = 0.01
# alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

> Warning message:
>   In adf.test(tsr1$LOAD.MW., alternative = "stationary") :
>     p-value smaller than printed p-value

What should I consider? Though I have feeling that it is non stationary. If it is, how to make it stationary using R? Also I tried using command
`decompose(tsr)`. It showed an error:

> ERROR  :   time series has no or less than 2 periods

What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The first step should be to visually examine your time series to see if it is stationary, and thereafter use the ADF-test to "formally" test for stationarity. This is more or less the standard procedure, at least in finance literature. (You could of course use another test like the KPSS or PP)

When plotting the ACF or PACF functions you mainly examine the AR and MA representation of your series.

As your series seems to be stationary according to the ADF-test you don't have to "make it stationary". However please keep in mind that these tests might give you the "wrong" answer when dealing with small sample data, seasonality or structural breaks.

If you don't want to soley rely on the ADF-test, you also could consider the KPSS test which have the opposite null-hypothosis.

Comment: i tried KPSS and its showing the opposite result  that of ADF- test..Which test to believe ?

Comment: If you mean opposite result as you may not reject the null-hypothesis in the KPSS test, you could be quite certain about that the series is stationary. If you reject the null in a ADF-test (i.e. a low p-value) the series is stationary. If you cannot reject the null in a KPSS-test (i.e. a high p-value) the series is stationary.